# $("input[class^=map]") not work for dropdown box in jquery

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how can I get the ID and class name from the dropdown box in jquery? I have been using the following code

```
var my_array = array[];
$("input[class^=map]").each(function(index, element) {
    my_array.push(this.id + "-" + this.className);
});
```

to get the ID and class name from the following code. This is working fine for TextBox but not dropdown box. Does anyone know what is it going on here? and how can I solve this issue?

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" CssClass="mapTest" />
  <asp:DropDownList ID="test1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsTestType" CssClass="maptest1"
    DataValueField="test_code" DataTextField="test_desc" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

I would like the end result be like this:

```
my_array[0] = test-maptest
my_array[1] = test1-maptest1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(":input[class^=map]").each(function(index, element) {
     my_array.push($(this).attr("id") + "-" + $(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't work, because DropDownList is generated as a:

```
<SELECT .....>
```

Instead of what you are looking for with jQuery:

```
<INPUT...>
```

Comment: any way that I can make two condition in the above code like, if input found or select found, then I assign into array? will it possible?

Comment: You should make more general selector as JohnP mentioned: $("[class^=map]"). So it will accept any element that has class containing "map" string.

Comment: It can also select non form input elements

Comment: It depends on what elements will you want to accept. If only form elements then the :input selector (as Quincy pointed) should be better solution than the more general one. But this is up to you... you have to choose, what elements are you going to check.

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector

```
$("[class^=map]").each(function(index, element) {
    my_array.push($(this).attr('id') + "-" + $(this).attr('class'));
});
```